# DynamoDB query get more than 1m of data - example in Java

Tags: java, amazon-dynamodb

I'm trying to run a query and get all items. it seems that not all items are retrieved and I need to run the query again with the start key.

From the documentation

> For either a Query or Scan operation, DynamoDB might return a LastEvaluatedKey value if the operation did not return all matching items in the table. To get the full count of items that match, take the LastEvaluatedKey value from the previous request and use it as the ExclusiveStartKey value in the next request. Repeat this until DynamoDB no longer returns a LastEvaluatedKey value.

Can you give a code example how to wrap this code to run the query again with the lastEvaluatedKey?

```
        QuerySpec spec = new QuerySpec()
    .withKeyConditionExpression("userName = :userName and #a between :startRange and :endRange")
    .withValueMap(valueMap)
    .withScanIndexForward(false)
    .withNameMap(nameMap);
        
    ItemCollection<QueryOutcome> items = table.query(spec);

    Iterator<Item> iterator = items.iterator();
    while (iterator.hasNext()) { ....
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using the [DynamoDB Document API](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/JavaDocumentAPIItemCRUD.html) and not the low level API.  When you are [querying](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/QueryingJavaDocumentAPI.html) using the Document API all of the low level considerations such as paging are taken care for you, but you can optionally interact with these lower level aspects.

Based on the code snippet you provided, the Document API library will take care of loading in additional pages when you reach the end of each page so there is nothing extra you need to do, your code should work!  This is the real benefit of using the Document API because it takes care of a lot of redundant boiler plate code for common use cases.

Comment: Thanks. Are you sure? when i run with the low level api (do ...while (lastEvaluatedKey != null) ) I'm getting much more results then the regular 'looping' (Iterator<Item> iterator = items.iterator(); while (iterator.hasNext())... also setting the max results and pages didn't help. Am i missing something? thanks again - Fredy

Comment: In my experience the document API does the paging automatically (one of its major benefits) and will retrieve all of the matching results for both queries and scans.  One way to prove this to yourself is to call `setMaxPageSize` on the QuerySpec and pass a small number, such as 2, and you will see that it returns more than 2 results.